# Is a module a limit of n-presented modules?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, projective-module

Let n be an integer. A module M is said to be n-presented if there exist an exact sequence of the form
$$ F_{n}\to  F_{n-1}\to ...\to F_{1}\to F_{0}\to M \to 0$$ with every $F_{i}$ is a finitely generated free module for example if n=0 M is said to be finitely generated and for n=1 M is called finitely presented. We know that every module is isomorphic to a filtred colimit of finitely presented module. I want to know if the results still true for any n, i.e, Is every module is a direct limit of  n-presented modules ?

Comment: If you want to improve your question, you could mention that for $n=0$ (resp. $n=1$) this means that every module is naturally the direct limit of its finitely generated (resp. finitely presented) submodules. It helps people situate the question. You could also mention why you think it could/should be true (or false) for $n=2$, if you have an idea.

Comment: Since you have changed the body of the question, please also change the question itself.

Comment: Downvoted because the question was changed after getting a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: the question has now changed. This answer addressed the original question, whether any module is a direct limit of $n$-presented *submodules*. (The question now asks about a direct limit of $n$-presented *modules*.)

Let $k$ be a field and let $R=k[x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots]$. Then $k$ has the structure of an $R$-module with each $x_i$ acting trivially. The module $k$ has no nontrivial submodules and is not itself $n$-presented for any positive integer $n$, so it won't be the direct limit of its $n$-presented submodules.

Comment: Isn't $k\simeq R/(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ as an $R$-module, and therefore $0$-presented (ie finitely generated)?

Comment: Yes, it's finitely generated, but I believe not $n$-presented for any positive $n$.

Comment: (I edited to add the restriction $n>0$.)